# how to get count(*) from table which either has column or not?

Tags: count, mysqli

I have a post table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `p_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `view_count` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `abstract` text CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `meta_description` tinytext CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `pic_id` (`picture`),
  KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `post_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `karbar` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `post_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`cat_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`cat_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And I have a comment table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `site` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text CHARACTER SET ucs2 COLLATE ucs2_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `p_id` (`p_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `comment_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `post` (`p_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to get one post(e.g p_id=8) and all of its comments. how to do that? How to get count(*) from comment table while your getting your post record?

Comment: Do you want to get all of the comments in a single SQL statement, or a given post plus a count of the comments in a single row? Your question is confusing.

Comment: One post with count of the comments.

Comment: A `SELECT * FROM post AS p INNER JOIN (SELECT p_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM comment GROUP BY p_id) AS c ON c.p_id = p.p_id` should do

Comment: I tried this but this is not the right solution for me, when there is no comment I still want to get the result set from post and 0 from cnt. your query gives nothing if we don't have a comment for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get all posts and their comment counts

```
SELECT p.*,IFNULL(c.comcount,0) comment_count
FROM post p LEFT JOIN
(SELECT p_id,COUNT(1) comcount FROM comment GROUP BY p_id) c
USING (p_id);
```

This will get post for p_id=8  and its comment count

```
SELECT p.*,IFNULL(c.comcount,0) comment_count
FROM (SELECT * FROM post WHERE p_id=8) p LEFT JOIN
(SELECT p_id,COUNT(1) comcount FROM comment WHERE p_id=8 GROUP BY p_id) c
USING (p_id);
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with left join, so that's why I couldn't solve the issue! thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.*, (SELECT count(*) FROM Comment c WHERE c.p_ID = p.p_ID) CommentCount
FROM Post p WHERE p.p_ID = 8;
```

In this case a function isn't necessary because the nested query will always return a number even if the number is zero.  If you want to see the output for all accounts simply remove the `WHERE` clause.